# How to resolve black screen on WhatsApp for macOS?

Tags: applications, crash, bug

I have tried re-installing the app (deleting it and downloading a new file), but I still get the following screen on macOS 11.3 (Big Sur):

[image]

Anyone else getting this same issue, and how to resolve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was some kind of bug. This resolved itself eventually.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same black screen, it was fixed by updating the WhatsApp application. Clicked command + space, typed "App Store", found WhatsApp, and clicked update.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting an app & re-installing usually changes nothing.

If the app itself will not work on any particular OS, then the developers will have to fix it; however, if it's simply a setting in your own machine, then you need to find & clear all the settings files.

The first one to try is in `~/Library/Saved Application State/` The saved state for each app is then in a folder called `com.company.product/` [as I've no idea who makes What'sApp I'll leave that to you.] Once you find the folder just delete it & try launch again.

If that doesn't work, then there are many app removers on the web which will do a more complete job. One I've used many times over the years is [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware).
Launch it, drop your WhatsApp app onto it & see what it finds. Be careful you don't discard anything you might need to keep. It will find & delete all history if you let it, but you can uncheck files you need to keep. You can also show the locations of all files, so you can make copies in case anything goes wrong.

Once done, drag WhatsApp back out of the bin into Applications & try again. You can rinse & repeat this until you're sure you threw out just the correct files if it doesn't go smoothly first time.

One thing to note - any files you need to put back must be put back manually with this method. Only files that were deleted by the Finder will have a specific "Put Back" option once in the Trash.